# The built ffmpeg.exe is not working as expected

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg

In my c++ application, I want to use ffmpeg lib statically.

I downloaded the ffmpeg-3.4.1 source and built the statically linked ffmpeg using MINGW, Yasm and VS2015 Command prompt as follows,

1. Downloaded the msys2-x86_64-20161025.exe
2. On opening the MINGW command prompt, install the required gcc tool using command "pacman -S make gcc diffutils"
3. Renamed C:\msys64\usr\bin\link.exe to C:\msys64\usr\bin\link_orig.exe
4. Downloaded the yasm 32 bit exe and set it's path to PATH environment variable. ("%PATH%;D:\ffmpeg")
5. Run VS2015, and open MINGW- C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -use-full-path
6. On opening MingW, change pwd to ffmpeg. Run ./configure then make the make install.

The configuration is used : ./configure --prefix="build" --toolchain=msvc --arch=x86 --enable-yasm --enable-asm --disable-shared --enable-static

It is built successfully. I got the bin folder having ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe. The size of ffmpeg.exe is 18 Mb. Also the 7 libs as .a file.

I guess I have to convert.a files to .lib and use in application?

I wanted to confirm if I have built everything correctly. So I tried to convert a .webm file to mp4 using the built ffmpeg.exe. I found that the size of output file is very large and quality is too bad. The input.webm file size was only 15 Mb and output.mp4 file size was about 188 Mb.

Then I downloaded the statically link ffmpeg application from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. I see the size of ffmpeg.exe is about 35 Mb and It works fine. For same .webm file, it created .mp4 file only 44 Mb and quality is also ok. I figured out that it is built with lots of external libs.

Are external libs creating the difference or my built ffmpeg application is not right? Do I need all those libs in my application too in order to get similar output?

screenshot output.mp4 from built ffmpeg.exe(15 Mb)
[image: screenshot output.mp4 from built ffmpeg.exe(15 Mb)]

Comment: Output file size and other parameters can be configured as parameters to the ffmpeg binary (encoding, codec, quality...) 
https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Main-options

Comment: Check stream info of that bad mp4 file and encoding process. Which encoder did your build choose, and encoding arguments?

Answer (score -1):

Without external libraries linked in, FFmpeg can already do many (but not all) things you will want it to do, and it will also in many cases not be as good at them as it would be with the specialized libs.
So, in short, yes, you need those external libs for the majority of common cases (especially if it involves MP4 and other modern formats).

So that brings us to **building FFmpeg**:
Building FFmpeg is a nightmarish experience. And that is on linux, where it is the easiest.

On Windows, where you seem to need it, it reaches Lovecraftian levels of horror - which you already glanced at.

Thankfully, this wonderful helper script exists:
https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers
Set up a virtual machine running a recent Ubuntu (or other distro if you prefer) and follow the "Cross-compiling from a Linux environment" steps.
I do **not** recommend using the Windows pipeline with cygwin or msys, as that is just incredibly slow compared to doing it all natively on linux (or even in a VM).

The script is also extremely configurable, so you can make changes as you wish. In my case, for example, I removed the "--disable-shared" option from the build script as I needed a dynamic build.

Comment: Use https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite directly on Windows - no cygwin involved.

Comment: That still uses MinGW & MSYS, though. Both of which are simply slower than the "real deal" on linux - even on a VM. Edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: It takes me 2-4 mins to run configure, depending on options and 1.5-5 mins to build with `-j8`. Hardly "*incredibly slow*".  And sorry but "*Lovecraftian levels of horror*" is a gross exaggeration.

Comment: You can be sorry all you want, but that doesn't change the facts. Without build scripts like these, that is just what it is. FFmpeg is a great piece of software, but in my 10+ years of experience, I have never encountered  other software of that complexity that would have been as user-unfriendly in every aspect towards developers.

Comment: And with incredibly slow I mean the initial build of the biggest version, not subsequent ones after changes.